# I need to map a JSON string received from a server to a specific Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

All,

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetMerchantUsers", "Merchant")',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(JSON.parse(json), function (item) { return new Task(item) });
        self.tasks(mappedTasks);
    }
});
```

This calls an MVC controller that returns a list of objects from a JsonResult method. It works totally fine. However, I need to rewrite this method because there will never be more than one Task being returned from the server. When I return one task from the server, however, the .NET JsonResult method doesn't put '[' and ']' at the beginning and end of the json, so $.map() sees the PROPERTIES of the object as a collection, but I just want to map one object returned from the server to a task observable instead of multiple tasks to a tasks observable. I'm new to knockout...how do I map a single Json object, like i'm doing above for a collection. I'll be happy to provide more info if needed!

Also, I've already mapped the object to a generic JavaScript type, but I want to map it to my Task type specifically.

Comment: var parsed = JSON.parse(json);  parsed = typeof parsed == "array" ? parsed : [parsed];

Comment: Chris, this parses to a generic Object. I want an object of type Task.

Comment: Hit enter too soon.  Basically, test if it's an array, if not, add it to an empty array then call your map

Answer (score 2):

Since you're no longer processing a list, you don't need `$.map()` (since it just loops through and applies a function to every item in a list), you can just pass the parsed JSON reponse to your `Task` constructor...like so perhaps:

```
var mappedTasks = new Task(JSON.parse(json));
```

If your `self.tasks()` method expects a list, you can just wrap it:

```
self.tasks([mappedTasks]);
```